# get values from nested Dictionary using LINQ. Values of Dictionary are list of lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

How to get values from nested Dictionary using LINQ.  Keys in the Dictionary are integer. Values of Dictionary are list of lists. Seconday level list is a list of array holding integer value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, just to be clear, this is what you're working with: `Dictionary<int, List<List<int[]>>>`? Yikes.

Comment: @ Michael Petrota : Well i could able to write a LINQ query to retrieve list(which indeed has a list). I couldnt get the second level list which is holding array of int. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, List<List<int[]>>> dictionary = ...
var values = dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.SelectMany(z => z));
```

**Edit**: Didn't realize it was a list of lists, so modified to account for that.

Comment: it should be in this way, Dictionary<int, List<List<Int[]>>>

Comment: Thanks Kirk Woll it worked. This is fantastic place to get queries answered quick.